# Granting Execute Permission on SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I recently migrated a database to SQL Azure. When I try to execute a stored procedure on this database on SQL Azure, I receive the following error:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'Log_Save', database 'MyDatabase', schema 'dbo'.
```

My question is, how do I grant EXECUTE permissions to stored procedures (as well as read/write access to tables) on SQL Azure?

thank you!

Answer (score 37):

The trick is that you have to create a custom "executor" role and then grant execute permissions to it.

In your master DB, first create a user if you don't have one already:

```
CREATE USER MyUser FOR LOGIN MyLogin WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO
```

Then, in your new DB:

```
CREATE ROLE [db_executor] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE TO [db_executor]
GO

sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_executor', @membername = 'MyUser'
sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datareader', @membername = 'MyUser'
sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'db_datawriter', @membername = 'MyUser'
```

Comment: Thanks, this was right on the money! (should also be the accepted answer IMHO...)

Comment: Please elaborate on why a "trick" is required here. Was it needed at the time? Is this assuming there will be many users that need to be assigned to this role?

Answer (score 14):

Related to Joe Abrams' answer, you can grant execute permission to an individual user:

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO testuser
GO
```